# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function when trying to use gon.watch in cytoscape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cytoscape.js, gon

This is my code. It's part the configuration of a library for context menus, and get's triggered if I click on an item in the context menu. Then I see the error mentioned in the title.

```
{
  [...]
  onClickFunction: function (event){
    [...]
    gon.watch("nodes", {}, function(){})
  }
},
```

Comment: The Cytoscape team reviewed this question today but we weren't sure what you were trying to do nor how it related to Cytoscape and/org cytoscape.js. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @AlexanderPico I tagged it wrong, it's actually a question about cytoscape js, sorry.